# Android App Development - Swipe actions

Tags: android

I want to create an informative app that will display a list of content. Each entry in the list corresponds to a slide/page. Users can choose a slide to get to the page. From there, users can swipe left and right to get to other pages. There are many apps in the store like this. I just didn't know what they are called [Slider apps??]. Not sure, that's why I gave a big explanation of what I am planning to do.

Here's what I found out in Android to achieve this. Please correct me if I am missing something. Also please suggest if there's a better way to do this or if I am doing any overkill.

1. The content is stored in SQLite database so data can be managed and updated easily. This will also help users favorite a slide and I can capture the info in the db.
2. Use ListView to show the list of content
3. A ScrollView to display the content in the slide
4. Question - how do I implement the swipe action? Can I have one Activity to display the page and use it while loading a new page for the swipe action, or would I need multiple Activities?

Thanks.

Comment: This will help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Try the following link. it contains example source for swiping of images and tabs. [ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) I think it may helpful to you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Horizontal viewpager to accomplish you task. Here is one of the example [Horizontal ViewPager](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging) . Also there is a very good article with the example [here](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/horizontal-scrolling-pages/). Please do check it. It might be pretty much helpful.